# Storing multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for the users on my site. The table consists of the the columns

```
user_id, fname, lname, email, password, interest1, interest2, interest3, interest4,   
interest5
```

Now, It's turning out to not be so practical to store the interests individually like so. What is a better way to do this. A way that keeps it easy to edit/access user interests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) does what you want.

You'd create a new `interests` table with structure like this:

```
interest      user_id
"skiing"          1
"programming"     4
 etc...
```

Then, you can get all the interests for a given user with a query like this:

```
SELECT `interest` FROM `interests` WHERE `user_id` = :my_user_id;
```

Comment: That's still not normalized. A normalized form would make use of a many-to-many relationship. So one table for interests only (id, interest_name) and one for relationship with users (user_id, interest_id).

Answer (score 2):

You have a many-to-many relationship between users and interests. Create a seaparte table of interests and introduce a junction table to link users with their interests.

[image]

Comment: This answer alone doesn't explain much except in book terms, and also your table has too much whitespace. (+1 anyways though.)

Comment: @arxanas: Fixed the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new table named `interests` with columns `user_id` and `interest`.

Answer (score 0):

[Serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) them. This way you can store zero to as many interests you they want and when you [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) them you can maintain the same data structure (i.e. array or object) that you created them with.

Comment: When you can normalize, why serialize? It makes searching impossible.

Comment: Why? Because it popped into my head as a simple, viable solution. I've got nothing against normalization.